# Why is my sidebar getting pushed underneath the main page content?

Tags: html, css

By creating unequal columns with CSS, I've attempted to divide up the page into a large column with main content (`.leftcolumn`) and slimmer column (`.rightcolumn`) that serves as a sidebar. However, the sidebar is getting pushed underneath the main content unless I make the width of either column 2% less than what it is.

I tried switching the order of the tags [as recommended by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696580/why-is-my-sidebar-being-pushed-below-content), but this had no effect. I also tried to give a `display: flex` property to the main content [as suggested by answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330757/sidebar-getting-pushed-down), but this only combined the two sample posts in the main content along one row while having no effect on the sidebar. Something else I tested was to assign `position: relative` to the main content and `position: absolute` to the sidebar, which was [the solution given by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561746/page-content-appearing-underneath-sidebar), but this had no effect on the actual display. I also tried @rajneesh-tiwari's suggestion below to define `z-index: 999` under the sidebar's parent container, but this, too, had no effect on the display.

My code is partially based on an example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_website_layout_blog) (the original runs fine there) and is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  * {
    font-family: Verdana;
  }

  body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.rightcolumn {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 25%;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Description</h5>
      <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Popular Post</h3>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Follow Me</h3>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I could just reduce either column's width by 2% (75% to 73% or 25% to 23%), but then the .leftcolumn does not align with the edge of my header (removed from the displayed code to reduce clutter), which kind of bothers me.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the padding that you put on the sidebar. (Padding doesn't take away from the width, so the sidebar is 25% + 20px padding, which is why it gets pushed down)

To fix this remove (subtract) the padding from the width of the sidebar, or the leftcolumn.
I like to use calc() to do this. In the example below I removed 20px from 25% on the .rightcolumn.

```
width: calc(25% - 20px);
```

Just remember that any padding you add will add to the total width and make it more than 100%, which is why it didn't work.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  * {
    font-family: Verdana;
  }

  body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.rightcolumn {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;   
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Description</h5>
      <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Popular Post</h3>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Follow Me</h3>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use flexbox, delete the floats and clears. Then make the parent container (.row) a flex box (display: flex). Then, instead of a width property on the column elements, use the flex property. For example, you can give the left column "flex: 5" and the right column "flex: 1".

Comment: This solution also worked, by the way -- thank you. One question: What is the advantage of using flex over width? It seems to make no difference for me.

Comment: The flex property here is shorthand for flex-basis. The difference between that and width is that, obviously, the direction of a flex container can be set to column. In that case, flex-basis will determine the height of the element instead of the width whereas the width property would continue to determine the width. That's why I think, in most cases, flex/flex-basis is better when dealing with a flexbox.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```css
z-index:999
```

on the sidebar's parent container.

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) is used to position elements along the z-axis which is the depth dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this also had no effect.